# Pointers to strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, memory-management

I am a newbie to C programming. And I am confused with the chaotic behavior of pointers. Specially when it comes to strings and arrays.

I know that I can't write like,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int *number=5;
 printf("%d",*number);
}
```

Because clearly it will try to write to the 5th location of the memory.And that will crash the program.I have to initialize the "number".

But when it comes to strings I can write like,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
 char *name="xxxxx";
 printf(name);
}
```

And it works too. So that means it implicitly initialize the "name" pointer.I also know that  name=&name[0]  But I have found that name=&name too. How can it be?
Because, to me it looks two variables with the same name. Can anybody tell me how strings are created in memory?(All this time time I assumed it creates name[0].....name[n-1] and  another variable(a pointer) called "name", inside that we put the location of name[0].Seem to be I was wrong.)

PS:-My English may not be good and if somebody can give me a link regarding above matter that would be grateful.

Comment: The behaviour of pointers in C is not chaotic. It is well defined.

Comment: `name` is definitely different from `&name` if `name` is of type `char*`. it is only true if `name` is of `char[]` and that too only the value is same but not the type. for `char name[]` name is of `char[]` type but &name is of `char(*)[]`

Comment: Also, please ask a single question at a time, instead of putting everything that puzzled you in the same question.

Comment: sorry for putting several questions together.When something is unsure it raises more questions along with it?But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4):

C, like many programming languages, supports the concept of "literals" - special syntax that, when encountered, causes the compiler to create a value in a special way.

`-2`, for example, is an **integer literal**. When encountered, the compiler will treat it as a value of type `int` with the content of -2. `"..."` is a **string literal** - when encountered, the compiler allocates new space in a special memory area, fills it with data that corresponds to the chars you used inside the literal, adds a 0 at the end of that area, and finally uses a pointer to that area, of type `char*`, as the result of the literal expression. So `char* s = "hello"` is an assignment from something of type `char*` into a variable of type `char*` - completely legal.

You sneaked in another question here - why `a == &a[0]`. It's best to ask one question at a time, but the gist of it is that `a[n]` is identical to `*((a)+(n))`, and so:

```
&a[0] == &*(a+0) == a+0 == a
```

Comment: "-2" looks like string literal:-). perhaps you could use ``.

Comment: @user2247911 I don't know what `&[a]` is... in any case, it's best to ask it separately as a new question.

Comment: sorry about above statement. it should be a=&a.My mistake.But don't worry about that because later i realized you have already given me the answer i expected.

Comment: "and finally uses a pointer to that area, of type char*, as the result of the literal expression" Technically, the expression has array type, which gets implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element since it's used in a context that expects a pointer type.

Answer (score 2):

```
 char *name="xxxxx";
```

This creates a `char array`(const) in memory, and it will assign the address of 1st element of it to `name`. char* array names are like pointers. `&name[0]` means address of 1st element and `name` (In c,cpp just the `char *` array name will provide you with the address of 1st element too (bcos that is what was assigned to `name` in the 1st place itself)) also gives the same result.

The notation `name[i]` is translated as `*(name+i)` so u actually have a base address `name` to which you add subscripts. (calculations are as per pointer arithmetic) . `printf("%s", name)` is designed to print from start address to `\0` (which is appended to the end of strings created using `char*` a.k.a String literals)

Check [this](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm) too.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you those strings are actually arrays of characters. What you do with the line `char *name = "xxxxx";`: You construct an array of 6 character values (5 of them being `'x'` and the last one being `'\0'`). `name` is a pointer to that array.

That's how strings are normally handles in C, you have some kind of sequence of characters, terminated with a `'\0'` character, to tell functions like `printf` where to stop processing the string.

Comment: you could also add that `printf(name)` is bad practice

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider this piece of code:

```
 char *name="xxxxx";
```

What happens here is that the string `xxxxx` is allocated memory and a **pointer** to that memory location,or the `address` of that string is passed to the `pointer` variable `name`.Or in other words you initialize `name` with that address.

And `printf()` is a variadic function (one that takes one fixed argument followed by a random number of arguments).The first argument to `printf()` is of type `const char*`.And the string identifier `name` when passed as an argument denotes the base address of that string.Hence you can use

```
printf(name);
```

It will simply output `xxxxx`

`name=&name too. How can it be?`--Well that's a justified question.

Let me explain first with a real-world analogy. Suppose you have the first house in a row of houses in a housing society.Suppose it's plot number `0`.The other houses are on plots 1,2,3......Now suppose there is a *pointer to your house*, and there is another *pointer to the whole housing society's row*. Won't the two pointers have the same address, which will be `plot 0`?This is because a pointer signifies a single memory location.It's the `type` of the pointer that matters here.

Bringing this analogy to the string( array of characters), the `name` identifier only signifies the base address of the string, the address of its first character (Like the address of the first house).It is numerically same to the address of the whole string,which is `(&name)`,which in my analogy is the ROW of houses.But they are of different types, one is of type `char*` and the other is of type `char**`.

Comment: Downvoter, stop your "revenge" downvoting.Show me where I am wrong if you feel I am.

Comment: I didn't vote on your answer at all. And I deleted my comments on where you had a tiny mistake, after you corrected it. So if by chance you meant me by "revenge": I didn't I'm not into that.

Answer (score 1):

Basicly what happens when the C-compiler see the expression

```
char *name = "xxxxx";
```

is, it will say. Hey `"xxxxx"` that's a constant string (which is an array of bytes terminated with a `0` byte), and put that in the resulting programs binary. Then it will substitute the string for the memory location, sort of like:

char *name = _some_secret_name_the_compiler_only_know;

where `_some_secret_name_the_compiler_only_know` is a pointer to the memory location where the string will live once the program gets executed. And get in with parsing the file.